# how to display the input values in the form after submitting the form to the same php page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i want to display the given input values in their respective input fields.I've tried using  javascript . But it doesn't help.

```
echo "<form class='navbar-form' method='POST' action='#'>"; 

$sqluser="SELECT DISTINCT username FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";
$resultuser=mysqli_query($conn,$sqluser);

echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='from_date' name='from_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='to_date' name='to_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><select  id='username' name='username' style='width:170px;height:33px;'>";
echo "<option select='selected'>-- Username --</option>";
while($ro1=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser))
{
    echo "<option value='".$ro1['username']."'>".$ro1['username']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input type='submit' value='submit'  onclick='showInput();'></div>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: did you do it by post?, or by Ajax post?

Comment: Before selecting you have to save that data to the DB. Where is the insert query ? or is it AJAX post ?

Comment: i don't want to insert the data in db. i want to fetch the data from db based on the user input. it is php POST. @Elby

Comment: it is php POST.I'm not using ajax . @ÁlvaroTouzón

Comment: ok, then i belive that you are reolading your page, so you need to use php to print the sended values under form

Comment: Sorry, my mistake @siri...

Comment: not under the form. i want to display them in the form. @ÁlvaroTouzón

Comment: yes you can set it under or as you want in, you can use $_POST ['xx'] to set values in form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi try following code...

```
echo "<form class='navbar-form' method='POST' action=''>"; 

$sqluser="SELECT DISTINCT username FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";
$resultuser=mysqli_query($conn,$sqluser);

if(isset($_POST['from_date']))
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='from_date' name='from_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' value='".$_POST['from_date']."'/></div>";
else
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='from_date' name='from_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";

if(isset($_POST['from_date']))
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='to_date' name='to_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' value='".$_POST['to_date']."'/></div>";
else
    echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='to_date' name='to_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";

echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><select  id='username' name='username' style='width:170px;height:33px;'>";
if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == "-- Username --")
    echo "<option selected='selected'>-- Username --</option>";
else
    echo "<option >-- Username --</option>";
while($ro1=mysqli_fetch_array($resultuser))
{
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $ro1['username'])
        echo "<option selected='selected' value='".$ro1['username']."'>".$ro1['username']."</option>";
    else
        echo "<option value='".$ro1['username']."'>".$ro1['username']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input type='submit' value='submit'  onclick='showInput();'></div>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: `select` should be `selected at line 26`

Comment: @Blueblazer172 : typo mistake :P...  updated... thnkx :)

Comment: this is working , but a small issue must be considered. my page takes either from date and to date as input or username as input. if i display the values by using this code, the dates values are posted again n it's corresponding code is executing. so, the control never enters the code that refers to username. @spankajd

Answer (score 1):

you can try following code:

```
<form class='navbar-form' method='POST'>
    <?php
        echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='from_date' name='from_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
        echo "<div class='form-group' style='margin-right:5px;'><input  id='to_date' name='to_date' type='date' data-date-inline-picker='true' /></div>";
    ?>
        <select name="username" type="text" id="username">
            <option value="">--Username--</option>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqluser);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $row["id"] == $_POST["username"]){
                        $optionSelected = "selected='selected'";
                    }else{
                        $optionSelected = "";
                    }
                    $userSet = "<option value='" .$row["username"]. "' ".$optionSelected.">".$row["username"]."</option>";
                    echo $userSet;
                }
            }
            $conn->close();
            ?>
        </select>
</form>
```

**Explanation:**

this should be the id of the user

```
$row["id"]
```

if you dont have an id of the user, replace this:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && $row["id"] == $_POST["username"]){
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) {
```

Answer (score -2):

use $_POST method in php
value attribute in input tag as follows:

```
value='<?php echo $_POST['form_date']; ?>'
```